# + foo + vs . foo . difference in php?

Tags: php, concatenation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

I can't seem to find the answer of what the difference is between

```
somephp" + foo + "morephp
```

and

```
somephp" . foo . "morephp
```

Dreamweaver recognizes both as syntactically correct. I just need an article link or explanation as the difference between them? Thanks! :)

My specific circumstance is I've got - CHILD_POS - which needs to be inserted into a static string. Basically... :

```
echo 'some stuff goes here' +/. CHILD_POS +/. 'some more stuff goes here';
```

I'm unsure whether to use (+) or (.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `.` character is specifically for string concatenation in PHP.  The `+` symbol is for math operations.

See the appropriate PHP manual pages:

[String Operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

[Arithmetic Operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)

Comment: `+` will convert both operands to a numeric type and then try to add them.  `"1" + "2" === 3` but `"1" . "2" === "12"`.

Comment: Answer upvoted - will accept in 10 minutes. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 6):

Using `+` will attempt to convert the string to a number, usually resulting in `0`.

Using `.` will concatenate the strings, which is what you almost always want.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use + for string concatenation in php. So no difference so discuss.

Comment: I guess I shouldn't have said + "doesn't exist" PHP. It does of course exist in math operations but you cant use both + and . for string  concatenation which Alex seems to have thought. That's what i meant.

Comment: I appreciate the clarification - as I did think both could be used for  strings.

Comment: +1 IMO this has been unfairly downvoted; it's an entirely true statement.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill It was downvoted before it was edited. I have reversed my vote in response.